# How to set a redux toolkit initial state to an array of object or localstorage with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, next.js

i'm currently trying to set an initialState (items) to an array of object or the same thing from the localStorage.
The problem is, that i'm receiving this kind of error.

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; price: number; quantity: number; totalPrice: number; name: string; }[]'.ts(2322)
> cart.ts(4, 3): The expected type comes from property 'items' which is declared here on type 'SliceState'

```
type SliceState = {
  items: {
    id: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    totalPrice: number;
    name: string;
  }[];
  totalQuantity: number;
  totalPrice: number;
};

const initialState: SliceState = {
  items: [] | localStorage.getItem("cart"),
  totalQuantity: 0,
  totalPrice: 0,
};


const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart(state, action: PayloadAction<any>) {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);
      state.totalQuantity++;
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
          id: newItem.id,
          price: newItem.price,
          quantity: newItem.quantity,
          totalPrice: newItem.price * newItem.quantity,
          name: newItem.name,
        });
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity += action.payload.quantity;
        existingItem.totalPrice =
          existingItem.totalPrice + newItem.price * newItem.quantity;
      }
      localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(state.items));
}
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what i'm trying to do ? I'm also using nextjs, i know ssr can be a problem with localstorage.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` returns string value, u need to parse it via `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax here:

```js
items: [] | localStorage.getItem("cart")
```

What you meant is:

```js
items: localStorage.getItem("cart") || []
```

Comment: Be careful, loliallen is right, you should also JSON.parse() the cart attribute because it will return a string. It should be:
```items: localStorage.getItem('cart') && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart') || []```